# Position number of li

Tags: html, list, css

I have a styled list, where every number is a circle. Moreover, this list is centered. I used to alter `top` attribute to position the number of a `li`. However - since this list has been through a lot -, now this attribute doesn't seem to help at first glance.

The problem is that circle of the number is not vertically aligned properly with its `li`, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/38/).

CSS:

```
.rounded-list a:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: relative;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: rgba(255, 168, 76, 0.5);
    display:inline-block;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

In the picture you can see where I would like the circle of the number to lie, in respect with its `li`.

[image]

Note that I had to move it a bit to the right for demonstrating purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can vertically center align these numbers by putting `vertical-align:middle` for `.rounded-list a:before` class and remove `margin-top` and `top:50%` from this.

Another solution is, we can use position absolute for ".rounded-list a:before" class and position:relative for its parent li and you can adjust numbers position by top and left.